# Method returning type 'nonetype' not type ''dict'

Tags: python, oop

I have a program that basically do this:

```
class principal():
    def execute(self):
        x = calculate()
        final = x.vars1()
        print str(type(final))

class calculate():
    def __init__(self):
        t = self.vars1()
    def vars1(self):
        a = {}
        for i in xrange(0,10):
            a[i] = i*10

        self.result(a)

    def result(self,r):
        return r


m = principal()
x = m.execute()
```

My return is "type 'NoneType'"
Why is not returning a dict type, witch is what I expect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no return in your method, hence it returns `None`.

Change your `vars1` method to:

```
def vars1(self):
    a = {}
    for i in xrange(0,10):
        a[i] = i*10
    return a
```

You can't call a method to do the return as you tried. The return statement allows you to return an object to the caller of the function. Your function `result` is basically returning the argument `r` to the method `vars1`. But `vars1` is not returning anything unless you put a return statement here too.

Answer (score 1):

you have to return a dict, your functions are not returning any values. This is sometime called falling off the end of a function. Each language treats this differently, but the most importent thing is to be explicit. For example in the function `vars1` you should add a `return` statement at the end:

```
def vars1(self):
    a = {}
    for i in xrange(0,10):
        a[i] = i*10

    return self.result(a)
```

Currently, `vars1(self)` is "falling-off the end" with no return value and Python will actually return a `NoneType`:

> The return statement returns with a value from a function. return without an expression argument returns None. Falling off the end of a function also returns None.

here is the [doc](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#defining-functions)

Answer (score 1):

You're not returning anything from the `vars1` method. You need to `return a` instead of `self.result(a)`.

Calling another function to `return` doesn't work the way it looks like you think it does. Your `result` method is essentially a no-op; it just returns its input back to whatever called it. It doesn't magically return that input out of some other method on the stack. Your `vars1` method has no `return` statement, and therefore it doesn't return anything.

Your flow looks kind of like this at the moment:

```
m.execute()
    creates x
    -> calls x.vars1()
        creates a
        -> calls x.result(a)
            -> returns a
            <-
        discards the return value of x.result()
        returns None
        <-
    assigns the return value of x.vars1() to final
    prints str(type(final)), which is None
```

What you want is for it to look like this:

```
m.execute()
    creates x
    -> calls x.vars1()
        creates a
        returns a
        <-
    assigns the return value of x.vars1() to final
    prints str(type(final)), which is a
```